# Does WebSphere API always provides MQ reason code when there is error from server side?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

While trying to extract the message from a Queue, I am getting the below error,

```
Original thrown object message: com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment$1: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue.
Stack trace:com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment$1: MQJMS2002: failed to get message from MQ queue.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.ConfigEnvironment.newException(ConfigEnvironment.java:379)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.getMessage(MQMessageConsumer.java:3082)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.receiveInternal(MQMessageConsumer.java:4544)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:4032)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:787)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:487)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:217)
        at com.myproject.mqqueue.JMSMQTest.extractMessages(JMSMQTest.java:220)
```

I could see the connection has been established properly and getting struck when i try to extract the messages. the current depth is also 20 and I wasn't able to extract the same.

**Someone could you please let me know, If I am doing something wrong or some configuration needs to be made.**

Also, Is it mandatory to have a Mq reason code if it is a server side problem like MQRC zzzz?

Added more info on the trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.JMSMessage._parseMcdFolder(JMSMessage.java:3486) 
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.JMSMessage._parseMcdFolderUtf8(JMSMessage.java:3627) 
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQJMSMessage.createJMSMessage(MQJMSMessage.java:607) 
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.isMessageSelected(MQMessageConsumer.java:3712) 
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.v6.jms.internal.MQMessageConsumer.getMessage(MQMessageConsumer.java:2745)
```

In regarding with the code, I don't do anything different there, Below are few parts

```
        QueueReceiver qReceiver;
        Message message;

        message=qReceiver.receive(3000); //Having problem while calling over here
```

Comment: Can you post your test code and full exception?

Comment: The Java NPE exception is being thrown when parsing the MCD folder which is apart of the RFH2 header on the message being consumed. I see from stack trace you are connecting to your qmgr using migration/compact (v6) mode but what version of the client are you using? Can you provide a dump of your message on the queue showing the RFH2 header?

Comment: Roger is being understated.  It isn't "a really good idea to also dump out the LinkedException" it's mandatory. JMS gives us a multi-level data structure for exceptions where the top layer is a generic JMS description of the error and the linked exception is the transport vendor's description of it. There is no justification for failure to print the linked exception. In most shops I've worked code that doesn't print the linked exception is considered to have a Sev-1 defect.  Why?  Because it's almost impossible to determine the problem without it as you are seeing based on responses here.

Comment: Also, If it is a server side problem, Does the MQ problem always comes up with an error code?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the message on the queue is not an MQRFH2 message.

It is a really good idea to also dump out the LinkedException. i.e.

```
catch (JMSException e)
{
   System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
   System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The LinkedException will contain the MQ Reason Code.